# How can i import a schema of a table from one database to an existing table in another without altering the data in it?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, import, schema

I want to import/copy a schema of a table from *e.g.* "DB1 database" another table in "DB2 database" without doing anything to the data in it. When I try to import the structure to the existing table it gives an error:

> " #1050 - Table 'access_logs' already exists "

Comment: No there isn't. You need to use ALTER table statements to bring db2 table definition in line with db1 table definition (or write code to generate the alter table )

Answer (score 0):

In phpmyadmin Go to 'Opeartions' Tab and then go to 'Copy Table to' section 
In that select the database in which you want to copy the table and give a name to the table.
You can choose options of Structure or Structure with data as per your requirements.